How can one check that someone truly has tinnitus, without relying on their claims?
I read on https://www.johnfoy.com/faqs/whats-wrong-with-3m-companys-dual-ended-combat-arms-earplugs-version-2-caev2/ (mirror):

To be eligible for the CAEv2 lawsuit specifically, you’ll need to have:[...]
Been diagnosed with tinnitus or hearing loss.

And https://veteranshelpgroup.com/tinnitus-proving-something-only-i-can-hear/ (mirror):

If you have regular or recurrent tinnitus 10% is given—currently, 10% warrants $140.05 a month.  Any additional hearing loss or other hearing conditions can be separately rated and combined. Because this is the most commonly claimed condition, veterans often start their claim journey by claiming tinnitus first.  Don’t forget to consider all other service-connected conditions too!

This made me wonder: How can one check that someone truly has tinnitus, without relying on their claims?
I searched for tinnitus diagnosis tests and all I could find seemed to rely on the claims of the patient, which I think, perhaps erroneously, could easily dupe a medical provider. For example, https://veteranshelpgroup.com/tinnitus-proving-something-only-i-can-hear/ indicates:

Because usually only the person impacted can hear the sound, the VA requires hearing and tests to confirm the diagnosis. Next, you should write your statement explaining the nexus between your condition and when in service you experienced the loud noise or another condition of which tinnitus is a symptom. Finally, gather and include documents like your medical records and a written physician’s opinion to support your claim.

which sounds easily fakable.

Isn't it self-evident that until we develop technology that can receive and interpret neural activity the same way our brains do that all such research relies on patient reports? But in my experience most fakers are easily spotted by an experienced provider.

@CareyGregory "most fakers are easily spotted by an experienced provider" how are they spotted?

Because they make small mistakes that someone with years of experience dealing with real patients will see.

@CareyGregory thanks, could you please give some example of such mistake? (genuine question, I'm very unfamiliar with tinnitus diagnosis)

Your search is missing how tinnitus is diagnosed. Check sources that mention audiologists. If someone doesn't see and care for patients with tinnitus on a somewhat regular basis, you probably shouldn't press them to tell you how malingerers might mess up (I'm not sure I could do it, and we did occupational medicine in our group, so hearing evals.) People who file for disability get referred to people who see the condition often; the more uncommon the condition, the more specialized the referral. @CareyGregory may not be able to give you the specifics, but he's still right.

I should also say, the more difficult to prove, the greater the need for a referral to a specialist. A lot of malingerers do get away with it, costing taxpayers or employers (or defendants) a good chunk of change. But the majority of conditions one might file claims for are familiar to most primary care providers.

@anongoodnurse is right; I know next to nothing about audiology and diagnosing tinnitus. If you want to talk about people faking some other things like unconsciousness, asthma, seizures, and sobriety, we can do that.

@CareyGregory - You just made me laugh out loud, remembering the 15 year old male who was faking unconsciousness to get out of a test at school and how I caught him out. It wasn't easy; his hand hit his face when dropped from above, he didn't flinch at all, and didn't react to unannounced toe pinpricks... I don't know how he defied all the tricks. But he could hear me quite well when I asked the adult who accompanied him to please leave the room so that we could collect a necessary (fluid) sample to test for drugs... whereupon he woke up and 'fessed up. I really had to work for that one!

@CareyGregory That's interesting too, e.g. for consciousness, there are some well-established tests as mentioned on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_stimulus

@FranckDernoncourt - I'm sorry if I seem to be picking on you (I'm not trying to; it's just something you might want to know.) Those maneuvers are used more to assess the "level of consciousness" (it varies; someone who faints is unconscious at a different level than someone with head trauma from a 5 story fall. Those maneuvers (and others) are used to determine the Glasgow Coma Scale. You can do some of those things with a malingerer, but there are tricks specific to malingerers that are more specific, like the hand held over the face and dropped.

@anongoodnurse Thanks I appreciate the information. I'm only using Stack Exhange to learn and retain knowledge, so anything in that direction is very welcome! I didn't know the Glasgow Coma Scale, and you're correct that my previous comment failed to address malingerers (which is a word I've just learned thanks to you).

There are no diagnostic tests that can objectify/confirm the experience of subjective tinnitus, other than searching for an underlying cause of tinnitus. In fact, if you ask me, there are generally no medical tests that can confirm the sensation of a symptom. As a parallel, if someone could objetify the experience of pain and quantify it with some kind of test, this would be big news in the scientific world. Most tests are designed to diagnose underlying conditions that may lead to specific symptoms.
Tinnitus is particularly tricky because it can occur even in the absence of a detectable disease. Additionally, we still lack sufficient answers regarding how or where tinnitus arises in healthy individuals. (Other than it is most often associated with factors such as acoustic trauma, presbyacusis.)  Does the sensation of sound originate from the inner ear, or somewhere along the neural pathway to the auditory cortex? While many theories exist, none are conclusive.
This is not to say there aren't several conditions known to cause tinnitus. These conditions can often be more or less confirmed through various tests or imaging techniques (e.g., vestibular schwannomas, meningiomas, Ménière’s disease, glomus tumors, large vestibular aqueduct, bone dehiscence around the inner ear, tensor tympani syndrome, and vascular abnormalities).
In clinical practice, I believe there is no need for an objective test to verify the sensation of tinnitus, except in cases where "objective tinnitus" is suspected, such as with tensor tympani syndrome.
Your question, however, relates to cases where individuals might seek financial compensation for tinnitus resulting from acoustic trauma. I am also surprised by how this is handled, as tinnitus can indeed be easily "faked". If a person says that they experience tinnitus it is not possible to refute this even though a thourough medical examination (physical exam, audiometry, MRI, CT etc.) returns without pathological findings.
However, audiometric testing can aid in differentiating hearing loss caused by acoustic trauma from presbycusis (age-related hearing loss). A typical audiometric pattern in cases of acoustic trauma shows worse hearing around 4000 Hz (it looks like a spike down in the audiogram, google it!). While audiometric testing is not entirely objective (it is called psychoacoustic testing for a reason), it is much harder to fake. If a person has a typical audiogram pattern of acoustic trauma while experiencing tinnitus, it would be easier to conclude that the tinnitus might be caused by the acoustic trauma.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK578179/
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK430809/

I don't think either of your references actually support this answer.

@anongoodnurse did you have anything in particular in mind?

Your first paper is just an "intro to audiometry" kind of paper, the second, similarly, just an "intro to tinnitus" paper. The question is about claiming tinnitus when there is none. You stated it was easily faked. Do you have evidence of that? There is a great deal of literature about tests for subjective tinnitus and their reliability.

I would be happy to have a look at this literature you are speaking of. I know of litterature about different MRI techniques and EEG which try to better understand the pathophysiology of tinnitus. There is, to my knowledge, no objective test to confirm the presence of tinnitus in a patient used in clinical routine. Except from tests/imaging techniques destined to find underlying causes of (subjective) tinnitus, such as tinnitus caused by vestibular schwannomas (MRI) or acoustic traumas (audiometry). I see my answer can be misinterpreted. I have adjusted it accordingly.

I didn't "misinterpret" your answer. 30-40% of US citizens have tinnitus, probably more because it's under-reported. With that many sufferers, there's a whole lot of literature, and the literature is plentiful on the reliability of tests for subjective tinnitus. Please don't commit the error of equating disagreement with misunderstanding. You didn't make your case. It's that simple.

The study {1} mentions:

Imaging can identify the cause and evaluate the extent of disease for surgical planning. The common causes of tinnitus and hearing loss without a mass include otospongiosis, labyrinthitis ossificans, superior semicircular canal dehiscence, and enlarged vestibular aqueduct syndrome.

nyulangone.org mentions cranial nerve issue as another potential cause:

An MRI scan may reveal a growth or tumor near the ear or the eighth cranial nerve that could be causing tinnitus.

{2} mentions more imaging options. So images could help detect fraudsters to some extent.
mayoclinic.org outlines typical tinnitus tests:

To help identify the cause of your tinnitus, your doctor will likely ask you about your medical history and examine your ears, head and neck. Common tests include:

Hearing (audiological) exam. During the test, you'll sit in a soundproof room wearing earphones that transmit specific sounds into one ear at a time. You'll indicate when you can hear the sound, and your results will be compared with results considered normal for your age. This can help rule out or identify possible causes of tinnitus.

Movement. Your doctor may ask you to move your eyes, clench your jaw, or move your neck, arms and legs. If your tinnitus changes or worsens, it may help identify an underlying disorder that needs treatment.

Imaging tests. Depending on the suspected cause of your tinnitus, you may need imaging tests such as CT or MRI scans.

Lab tests. Your doctor may draw blood to check for anemia, thyroid problems, heart disease or vitamin deficiencies.



The audiologist may detect fraudsters if they give atypical answers, but it seems that a well-informed individual may be able to fake the condition as there is no definitive, objective test.

References:

{1} Hoang JK, Loevner LA. Evaluation of Tinnitus and Hearing Loss in the Adult. 2020 Feb 15. In: Hodler J, Kubik-Huch RA, von Schulthess GK, editors. Diseases of the Brain, Head and Neck, Spine 2020–2023: Diagnostic Imaging [Internet]. Cham (CH): Springer; 2020. Chapter 15. Available from: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK554328/ doi: 10.1007/978-3-030-38490-6_15
{2} Khan, R.A., Sutton, B.P., Tai, Y. et al. A large-scale diffusion imaging study of tinnitus and hearing loss. Sci Rep 11, 23395 (2021). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-021-02908-6


Your answer concerns the differential diagnosis of tinnitus, not means of confirmation.  I'm not sure that most tinnitus can't be confirmed with the proper audiometric testing. I don't know if the average well-informed individual can isolate the exact same sound frequency every time unless they hear it all the time, and it matches the tinnitus exactly. That's one way audiolgists catch malingerers. (If they were really inventive, they might pick a common pitch and practice identifying it, but still, in a sound-proof room with a good tester, it might be pretty difficult.)

Also, (and I don't have specifics about this, so grain of salt) tinnitus often has more than one component. E.g. it can be a fluctuating low buzz + a higher pitch clear tone, etc. But as I said, no numbers to support. It would be harder to pretend consistently if there was more than one component.

@anongoodnurse thanks, great points. That'd be helpful if someone with a strong knowledge of tinnitus could write an answer. "can isolate the exact same sound frequency every time unless they hear it all the time, and it matches the tinnitus exactly" sounds like a good way to detect many fraudsters indeed.
